# Why 3 ways to do MVC 5 Model Binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model-binding

I'm reading Professional ASP.Net MVC 5 and the section on Model Binding shows 3 ways to do the same thing.  They are listed below.  Can anyone explain the pros and cons of each method?

The first example uses if ModelState.IsValid
the second example uses if TryUpdateModel
The third uses both.

What am I missing here?  All seem to work.  Why 3 ways to write it?

```
[HttpPost] 
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public ActionResult Edit (Album album)
    { 
      if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        { db.Entry( album). State = EntityState.Modified; 
          db.SaveChanges(); 
          return RedirectToAction(" Index"); 
        } 
        return View( album); 
        }
     View( album); 
    }

[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Edit() 
    { 
     var album = new Album(); 
     if (TryUpdateModel( album)) 
         { db.Entry( album). State = EntityState.Modified; 
           db.SaveChanges(); 
           return RedirectToAction(" Index"); 
         } 
           else 
         { 
           return View( album); 
         }
    }

[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Edit() 
    { 
      var album = new Album(); 
      TryUpdateModel( album); 
      if (ModelState.IsValid) 
          { 
            db.Entry( album). State = EntityState.Modified; 
            db.SaveChanges(); 
            return RedirectToAction(" Index"); 
          } 
            else 
          { 
            return View( album);
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first is very simple and supports the most common use where simply newing up the model and mapping the data to it is fine. The instance creation and mapping is handled automatically and "just works".

The third allows you map the incoming data to an existing object instance. If for some reason you already have an object instance you want to map the data too (it probably already has extra data in you want to use and that data doesn't exist in a new instance MVC would automatically create) then this is how you would do it.

The second is the same as the third, but allows you to differentiate between "The model failed to update" and "the model updated, but is invalid".